# how to shift panels dynamically

Tags: ibm-bpm

```
-----------------------
|        Panel 1      |
-----------------------
|  add     |   remove |
-----------------------            

-----------------------
|        Panel 2      |
-----------------------
|  add     |   remove |
-----------------------
```

Is it possible to implement a logic whereby panel 2 shifts above panel 1 when both are initially opened, then panel 1 is removed and subsequently added by the add button in panel 2?